# Where is the Rules Evaluation Log?

Tags: rules

Where is the Rules Evaluation Log?  I need to view it but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

There are typically 2 ways of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) debugging, as further detailed below.

## 1. Rules Evaluation Log

Within the Rules **settings** (located at `admin/config/workflow/rules/settings` in your site), experiment a bit with the debugging facilities that come with the Rules module. More specifically, within the "**debugging**" section of that page, you should change the value of "*Show debug information*" to "*Always*". Be aware also of what's mentioned at the end of that same debugging section, i.e.:

> Debug information is only shown when rules are evaluated and is visible for users having the permission Access the Rules debug log.

So double check (at `admin/people/permissions#module-rules`) that for the userid you're using you've granted the required permission.

#### Example of a Rules evaluation log

Here is an example of such Rules Evaluation Log:

[image]

#### URL to view the Rules Evaluation Log

There is not really "an" URL you can go find this log. Such Rules Evaluation log only gets displayed whenever "some Rules event happens" (for a rule that is enabled, disabled doesn't count ...). Like in my sample screenprint: that log is shown right after some user performed a login (because in this site there was an enabled rule that used event "User logged in"). Also, assume you just have 1 enabled rule, using a Rules Event X, then you need to "make something happen" in your site that triggers that Rules Event (if the event is not triggered, then you wouldn't see any logging data).

## 2. Rules Action to display a value (using devel)

You may also want to (temporary) enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, so that you can (temporary) add a Rules Action like "Display a value". That's not within Rules Conditions (as in your question), but if you add that as your first Rules Action, then you can be sure that the values displayed are identical to the value of these variables at the end of the Rules Conditions.

Obviously, make sure that there are no Rules Conditions that would prevent the rules Action(s) from being executed (if needed temporary remove such Rules Conditions).

## 3. Resources

- **Community documentation**: [Tools for testing & debugging Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1593278) contains the official community documentation about Rules debugging.
- **Video tutorial**: Refer to the (great!) video "[Debugging rules configuration](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/debugging-rules-configuration)" for way more details about these 2 debugging variations.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Comment: Hi Pierre.  Thank you for answering.  Are you able to give the specific url to where I can view the Rules Evaluation Log because I can't find it?

Comment: Thanks again.  Now I am confused, sorry.  In the original answer you say "Have a look at the "Rules Evaluation Log"", and from the logic of the language it appears it has a static location I can go to.  In the the comment you say "that log is shown right after some user performed a login" .  Shown where?

Comment: @Craig as Pierre mentioned there is no URL. It's not really a log like the Watchdog log it's just a list of events, conditions, and then actions that gets shown on every page load. If you don't see the output, then no events were triggered.

Comment: @Craig check my updated answer, does it help to address your prior comments?